# AsyncTask is not run from start when the Activity is created

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm facing a problem: I created two Activities.
One is the main Activity, which has a Button.
When I click this Button, the  second Activity starts.
The second Activity uses an `Asynctask` in which a number is incremented from 1 to 10 and displays this number in a `Textview`

What I'm facing is that when I click the back Button while the `Asynctask` has not completed and then again go to the second Activity the `Asynctask` is not run from start immediately.

I know because in background when it completed the old task then it again starts a new task. Is there a way to fix this when destroying the Activity it also destroy the `Asynctask`?

Here is [video sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxFIcdBBsfZoMk05MHRCS0o1WWs) for my problem.
Code for Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button bt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);

        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondAcitivity.class);

                startActivity(i);

            }
        });


    }
}
```

Code of Second Activity:

```
public class SecondAcitivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView t1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_acitivity);


        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
        OurWork obj = new OurWork();
        obj.execute();

    }


    class OurWork extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            int i = 0;
            while (i < 11) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(700);
                    publishProgress(i);
                    i++;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return "Successfully Completed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

            t1.setText(values[0] + "%");

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            t1.setText(result);

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: you can call yourAsyncTask.cancel(true); at back button press. Then the asyncTask running actually is beeing canceled....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs can you do this with a code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to cancel the task on back pressed, and you need to monitor if the task is canceled while executing the `doInbackground()`.

1- override onbackpressed:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    obj.cancel(true); // where obj is the asyncTask refernce object name
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

2- monitor `isCanceled()`

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    int i = 0;
    while (i < 11 && !isCancelled()) { // added !isCancelled()

        try {
            Thread.sleep(700);
            publishProgress(i);
            i++;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return "Successfully Completed";
}
```

on next iteration of the while loop, after `cancel(true);` is called,the loop will quit, and `doInBackground()` will return.

Comment: it's working one last thing is it necessary to write this line when we override AsyncTask methods like this `super.onPostExecute()` and what `super.onBackPressed()` do?

Comment: @hamel123 `super.onPostExecute()` is not needed, but in other cases of overriding you may have to write it, it depends on the parent (super) class, it means you are calling the same method `onPostExecute()` or `onBackPressed()` that exists in the parent class, read more about object oriented, overriding, overloading if you want to learn more

Answer (score 0):

When you press back button , `onBackPressed callback` is called. so you can basically try this :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (asyncFetch.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
       asyncFetch.cancel(true);
    } 
    finish(); 
}
```

Comment: i try your method but same problem happen on back button!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :

```
private OurWork task;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_acitivity);


    t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
    task = new OurWork();
    task.execute();

}

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        task.cancel(true);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask runs in background of the activity where it was hosted. If OnPause or OnDestroy is called, AsyncTask is destroyed, so to solve this issue, Override OnResume and execute AsyncTask again.

Comment: when i press back button i want to destroy the AsyncTask

Comment: okay set i as global int then onPause  or onBackPess set  i = 11 that will destroy the AsyncTask whilel on resume set i = 0 and execute AsyncTask again.

Answer (score 0):

To cancel the asyncTask even when it is running when back is pressed, add this to onBackPressed:

```
 public class SecondAcitivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView t1;
    static OurWork obj;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_acitivity);


        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
        obj = new OurWork();
        obj.execute();

    }


    class OurWork extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            int i = 0;
            while (i < 11) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(700);
                    publishProgress(i);
                    i++;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return "Successfully Completed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

            t1.setText(values[0] + "%");

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            t1.setText(result);

        }


    }

    //override onBackPressed and do this
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (obj!=null && (obj.getStatus()== AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING ||
                obj.getStatus()== AsyncTask.Status.PENDING ))
            obj.cancel(true);

        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```